# Input matrix to function file of ode45

Tags: matlab, function, ode, ode45

I have a code(which requires a lot input be given by the user) which will give me a n x n matrix(say A), which I have to use to solve a system of ODEs X'=AX. How do I include this matrix A in the function file(.m file) of ode45. If I include the code in the function file as below:

```
function xp=g_test(t,x);
k=input('something');
A=some manipulation of inputs;
xp=A*x;
end
```

Matlab asks for input at each timestep(typically my problem has 30k timesteps). So how do I include/ pass the matrix A to the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a function that returns a [function handle](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html):

```
function odeFcn = makeODE(a,b,c)  
    A = some_function(a, b, c);
    odeFcn = @(t,x) A*x;
end
```

Now you can call `ode45` with input matrices `a, b, c`:

```
outputVector = ode45(makeODE(a,b,c), [t0, t1], x0);
```

---

The inspiration is taken from gnovice's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1575968/2338750).